# variable in list producing incorrect boolean variable

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, operators

So in my code, I have a list (`game.patrolled`) being accessed, and when I print the list, I get:

`[40, 44, 46, 39]`

This is what it should be, this part is correct.
When I print the variables (`x`) in my for loop, I get:

```
40
48
44
49
37
39
42
46
47
```

This is also what I should get, this part is also correct.
But when I have it print (`x in game.patrolled`) every time it loops for x, I get:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

This is wrong. I should have 4 of these values be True, since they are in the list, as you can clearly see above. Is there any reason as to why the "in" operator just doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I suspect `x` contains a string. Use `int(x) in game.patrolled`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that and it still is saying the same thing.

Comment: Show us the full code.  Don't make us guess what it is.

Comment: @JohnGordon If I showed you the full code you would have to read over 10000 lines of code in over 10 different python files

Comment: Try `print(repr(x))` in the loop where you check if x is in the list.

Comment: @JohnGordon Tried it, got the same result.

Comment: Please show us that output.

Comment: And at least show us the code for that loop.

Comment: @JohnGordon It showed similar results, but I just changed it to `x in repr(game.patrolled)` and that worked properly. Do you have an explanation as to why this worked? Does it have to do with my data types, maybe?

Comment: `repr()` returns a string.  So if `x in repr(game.patrolled)` returned true, then `x` _must_ be a string.

Comment: @JohnGordon That makes sense. But how come int(x) didn't work before?

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps you made some other error.  Without seeing the code, it's impossible to say.

Comment: @JohnGordon Fair enough haha. I don't even know everything in the code myself, it's a huge collaborative project and I'm only working on one particular part of it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I would warn you against using `repr()` though, because for string values, `in` also counts substrings.  So for example `"3" in "43"` is true.  I think you need to keep digging until you find the root cause.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `x in repr(game.patrolled)` will tell you if `x` is a substring of `repr(game.patrolled)`. So if `x == '1'` and `game.patrolled == [12]`, you'll get `True` from that, even though `int(x) in game.patrolled` is False.

Comment: Please post the output of `print(game.patrolled)` and `print(repr(x))`